# How to add a Deny ACE for TrustedInstaller?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, access-control

I'm having trouble deleting a file/folder. The operating system claims its in use even though its old and subject to deletion. The same problem occurs on occasion under both Windows 8 and Windows 10.

I was able to place a Deny ACE on the object for ***SYSTEM***, but I am having trouble putting one on the object for ***TrustedInstaller*** (or ***Trusted Installer***). It appears there is no security principal named ***TrustedInstaller*** in the SAM database, or the operating system is filtering results so I can't use the name:

[image]

How do I add a Deny ACE to an object for the TrustedInstaller security principal?

Comment: How is "I'm having trouble deleting a file/folder" related to that?

Comment: @grawity - I believe the component that has the file open runs under SYSTEM or TrustedInstaller; or it has the privileges associated with SYSTEM or TrustedInstaller.

Comment: Changing the ACLs wouldn't help with that at all though. Existing file handles remain open. File access is checked at open time.

Comment: try **NT Service\TrustedInstaller** and look what happens

Comment: @grawity - once I added the Deny ACE, I planned on a reboot. However, I looked at the file using [Sysinternal's handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) program and nothing has it open. I also used [Sysinternal's Move File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pendmoves) to force a deletion at reboot, but the deletion failed. I'm guessing its an ASUS driver using the old file and bypassing the [Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29). I returned the laptop because I got tired of trying to fix stuff with a new laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `NT Service\TrustedInstaller` [as entry to select TrustedInstaller permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2007/01/30/sysk-277-how-to-bring-back-the-trustedinstaller.aspx).